# net/http doesn't work in the Go Playground

Tags: go, go-playground

Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong. So basically I'am trying to make a simple HTTP `GET` request. I copied code from https://gobyexample.com/http-clients. When I'm running it locally everything works fine, but in go playground https://play.golang.org/p/-28ykONUD98 it gives:

> panic: Get "http://gobyexample.com": dial tcp: lookup gobyexample.com
> on 169.254.169.254:53: dial udp 169.254.169.254:53: connect: no route
> to host
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: main.main()    /tmp/sandbox181131075/prog.go:13
> +0x345
>
> Program exited: status 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://blog.golang.org/playground

> Like the file system, the playground's network stack is an in-process fake implemented by the syscall package. It permits playground projects to use the loopback interface (127.0.0.1). Requests to other hosts will fail.

So it's normal, your code is good but go playground can only connect to 127.0.0.1

Comment: This restriction is so that malicious users can't use the playground to execute attacks on 3rd party hosts.

Comment: how can we disable this restriction for self hosted go playground?